# count the occurrence of specific value in array

Tags: perl, count

I want to count the occurrence of specific value in array, the array as below.

```
my @array = (-1.001, -7.032, -5.013, 8.412, -1.500, 3.412)
```

The expected result 
For value under zero count = 4

For value under minus 5 count = 2

How can I get it using Perl, Any Idea?

Comment: Iterate over the array and count what you need.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `grep` to filter elements, and use it in scalar context when it returns number of list elements which passed the filter,

```
my $count1 = grep { $_ < 0  } @array;
my $count2 = grep { $_ < -5 } @array;
```

another way is to use `foreach` loop,

```
my $count1 = 0;
my $count2 = 0;
for (@array) {
  $count1++ if $_ < 0;
  $count2++ if $_ < -5;
}
```